# Angular Express redirect

Tags: angular, express, redirect, angular-universal

I have my ssr response service, with a redirect method among other:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Response } from 'express';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';

@Injectable()
export class SsrResponseService {
  constructor(@Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) {}

  redirect(url: string, code?: number) {
    if (!!code) {
      return this.response.redirect(code, url);
    } else {
      return this.response.redirect(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in my component I need to redirect the user if some conditions aren't met:

```
this.responseService.redirect('/some-other-url', 301);
```

The redirect works fine, the user is redirected, but the server logs:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't set headers after they are sent. ; 
Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/MrCroft/c8a659567a3b248744b62a7cc04f061d

What can I do differently to avoid the error?
Note that the decision can only be made from within the Angular application code.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other redirections after that? try Calling response.end() after the redirect maybe

Comment: Apparently, it eliminates the stack trace. But the part of the error that is mentioned directly in the question stil gets thrown. I've also found this in the mean time: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/491 , maybe it's related - although it's a very old issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found a workaround for it:

Instead of using `this.response.redirect(url, code)` use:

```
this.response.status(code)
this.response.setHeader('Location', url);
```

Error vanishes

Comment: This fixed it for me!